# R statistics output interpretation : ebook

Tags: r, references

I am basically a biologist working in genomic data analysis. I have started learning statistics and now am acquainted with basics of it. I can run several statistics commands on R.

I have plenty of pdfs which emphasise how to run R or how to perform statistical tests etc., but do not explain the output in a comprehensive way.

I am looking for a pdf for R statistics output interpretation, where the output is interpreted in a clear and lucid way.

Can anybody share an ebook or pdf having the interpretation of various statistical tests / models?

Comment: As @Penguin_Knight hints at, I think your main issue is understanding statistics, after which you can decide which R output  is useful.  Narrow your question to receive specific help.

Answer (score 4):

This question is probably too broad. R itself has many functions and the thousands of contributed packages only add complexity to your solution. Too be frank, you may have better luck to post a very specific question here, paste a certain part of the output, and ask for clarification on the components of question.

Having said that, there are some tips you can try:

1. [The R Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470973927) provides a pretty broad introduction to R. It gives some interpretation of outputs.
2. If you have question with a particular package, you can check if the [Use R! series](http://www.springer.com/series/6991?detailsPage=titles) of Springer has a title about it. Each of them is more specific and tend to spend more pages on discussing the outputs and interpretations.
3. If you just type any command without providing any argument (e.g. **lm**), you can see the source code and figure out how the calculation goes.
4. If you type **?** in front of any function, e.g. **?lm**, you'll see the help page of that function. If you scroll down, you'll find the literature the command is based on, reading those usually help clarifying some lingoes.
5. In a way, output interpretation is more about statistics than the software. Read up on the statistical technique you are using, and then play with some example along the way. Match the statistics from the books with the statistics from the R output, you can quickly establish a good understanding.
6. Perform a PDF search on Google using phrase like [R statistics filetype:pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=R+statistics+filetype%3Apdf). You may find useful e-books, tutorials, or syllabi.